# mvc5 linq error displaying selected information

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

I created a blank MVC5 controller which I was told to do, after creating a select statement with a multiway join clause I try to pass the selected information into the view but upon loading the view it crashes with this error:
"The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType6`5[System.DateTime,System.TimeSpan,System.String,System.Int32,System.String]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[snBusService04.Models.trip]'. "

This is my index view code

```html
 public ActionResult Index(string busRouteCode)
        {
            var tripInfo = "";

            if (busRouteCode != null)
            {
                HttpCookie busRouteCodeCookie = new HttpCookie("busRouteCodeCookie");
                busRouteCodeCookie.Value = busRouteCode;
                busRouteCodeCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1);
                Response.Cookies.Add(busRouteCodeCookie);
            }
            else if (Request.Cookies["busRouteCodeCookie"] != null )
            {
                tripInfo = Request.Cookies["busRouteCodeCookie"].Value;
            }
            else
            {
                TempData["message"] = "Please select a bus route";
               return RedirectToAction("Index", "snBusRoutes");
            }

            var tripQuery = from br in db.busRoutes
                            join rs in db.routeSchedules on br.busRouteCode equals rs.busRouteCode
                            join t in db.trips on rs.routeScheduleId equals t.routeScheduleId
                            join d in db.drivers on t.driverId equals d.driverId
                            join b in db.buses on t.busId equals b.busId
                           // where br.busRouteCode == busRouteCode
                            select new
                            {
                                t.tripDate,
                                rs.startTime,
                                d.fullName,
                                b.busNumber,
                                t.comments
                            };
            var queryResult = tripQuery.AsEnumerable()
                                .Select(t => new
                                {
                                    t.tripDate,
                                    t.startTime,
                                    t.fullName,
                                    t.busNumber,
                                    t.comments
                                });

             return View(queryResult.ToList());            
        }
```

the view code is as follows:

```html
@model IEnumerable<snBusService04.Models.trip>

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Monitored Trip Information for " + Request.Cookies["busRouteCodeCookie"].Value;
    }

    <h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>
    <h3>@TempData["message"]</h3>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.tripDate)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.startTime)
        </th>    
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.fullName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.busNumber)
        </th>       
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.comments)
        </th>   
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.tripDate)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.startTime)
            </td>  
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.fullName)
            </td>           
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.busNumber)
            </td>            
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.comments)
            </td>       
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your view is expecting an `IEnumerable<snBusService04.Models.trip>`

Change your query result to the following which returns the expected type rather than an Anonymous IEnumerable. (Assuming your fields match your naming structure):

```
var queryResult = tripQuery.AsEnumerable()
             .Select(t => new snBusService04.Models.trip
             {
                 tripDate = t.tripDate,
                 startTime = t.startTime,
                 fullName = t.fullName,
                 busNumber = t.busNumber,
                 comments = t.comments
              });
```

Comment: So i found out i dont need the query Result but now my problem is that the fields I need are in different tables. The trip table which my controller is for only has the ID values but I need the actual names/numbers of the records.
Actually I think i may be an idiot, just need to use model.driver.fullName etc.

Comment: @SteveN You should be able to join the other tables with a linq query. Create a new question, people are that quick at answering Linq questions I doubt it will be me that answers. :)   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx